# Graphql Mutation: Program Control doesn't return to either onResponse or onFailure after call

Tags: android, android-fragments, apollo-client, graphql-java

I am working on an app that implements Graphql in Android using Apollo Client support. I have a Graphql mutation that runs successfully in an Android Activity but when the same mutation is implemented in an Android Fragment it is not called at all. I mean the control never returns to either onResponse or onFailure method of the enqueue call.
It is called in the onActivityCreated method of the Fragment.

Am I missing something obvious?

Here is the mutation.

```
UserSignIn userSignIn = UserSignIn.builder()
.email("itxxxxd@gmail.com")
.password("xxxxx")
.build();
SignInMutation signInMutation = SignInMutation.builder().input(userSignIn).build();

ApiClient.getMyApolloClient().mutate(signInMutation).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<SignInMutation.Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<SignInMutation.Data> response) {
        if (response.data() != null) {
            Timber.w("SignIn Data onResponse: %s", response.data().signIn().token);
        }
        if (!response.errors().isEmpty()) {
            Timber.w("SignIn Error onResponse: %s", response.errors().get(0).message());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
        Timber.w("SignIn Error onFailure: %s", e.toString());
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not an issue with Fragments or Activity. It is simply that my Fragment ends with exception before the control returns to the onResponse or onFailure method. This is the obvious thing I missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in onViewCreated of the fragment instead

```
UserSignIn userSignIn = UserSignIn.builder()
    .email("itxxxxd@gmail.com")
    .password("xxxxx")
    .build();
    SignInMutation signInMutation = SignInMutation.builder().input(userSignIn).build();

    ApiClient.getMyApolloClient().mutate(signInMutation).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<SignInMutation.Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<SignInMutation.Data> response) {
            if (response.data() != null) {
                Timber.w("SignIn Data onResponse: %s", response.data().signIn().token);
            }else{
               //response can be null
    }
            if (!response.errors().isEmpty()) {
                Timber.w("SignIn Error onResponse: %s", response.errors().get(0).message());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
            Timber.w("SignIn Error onFailure: %s", e.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: As suggested I moved the call to onViewCreated but it is still the same. The Mutation is not called.